# Redirection in .htaccess for files in subdirectory, but not root of subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am having trouble finding the correct way to write a .htaccess redirection.

I want to invisibly redirect any page in a subdirectory:

http://my-site.com/test/any_page.php

to

http://my-site.com/AIMS/rewrite.php

However, I don't want to redirect the root subdir:

http://my-site.com/test/

The above url should not redirect. The problem with my rule is it redirects any page, and the root of the subdir as well.

I was unable to find any questions already asked for this specific case. Many thanks in advance for any tips on what I might be doing wrong.

Here are my rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /AIMS/rewrite.php?data=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your rewrite you're using the regex `.*` which means match **zero** or more characters - you want to match **one** or more.

Changing it to the below should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ /AIMS/rewrite.php?data=$1 [NC,L]
```